# Printing the whole command used by Visual Studio to compile a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

When we compile a C/C++ project in Visual Studio, the output window just prints the name of the file being compiled. How do we print the whole command? I.e., all the include directories, flags, etc. being used in compiling that file?

I know there is an option when we right click on a file name, *Properties* → *Command line*, which shows the command to be used while building, but I want it to get printed on the output window.

Answer (score 3):

You can see command line switches in BuildLog.htm file produced by Visual Studio. Use Ctrl+Click in the Output window link to see this file after building a project.

Also, reading this file, we can see that printing full command line in Output window will not help:

```
Creating temporary file "c:\tmp\test\Debug\RSP00000125403116.rsp" with contents
[
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug\test.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc80.pdb" /W3 /c /Wp64 /ZI /TP .\test.cpp
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\tmp\test\Debug\RSP00000125403116.rsp /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
```

So, Visual Studio creates temporary file with command line switches, and command line contains this file name.

**Update for new Visual Studio versions.** Tools - Options - Project and Solutions - Build and Run. MSBuild project build output verbosity. Select Detailed or Diagnostic to see more information in the build log (Output window).

Comment: Yes that is there but it generates a file for each target of one's project. Is there a setting 

Comment: Ctrl+Clicking the output doesn't work for me. Perhaps I'm clicking the wrong place? I've tried the actual tab itself, and the text within the tab.