# Compiling a file the same way Visual Studio does: include path not set

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584545/480982) to get the complete command line Visual Studio uses when I press Ctrl+F7 to compile a single file.

That command line is (formatted for readability)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\
                             VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe 
/c /ZI /JMC /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG 
/D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise 
/permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++20 
/Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC 
/errorReport:prompt StringFormatting.cpp
```

1. I open a Powershell prompt in the directory where `StringFormatting.cpp` is located.
2. I copy/paste the exact command line.
3. I add quotes around the executable name, so that there are no issues with spaces in the path.

The error message I get is

> [...] StringFormatting.h(2,10): fatal error C1034: string: no include path set

The first 2 line of the header file are

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
```

Obviously it can't resolve the `#include <string>` which is part of my code. How does Visual Studio tell the compiler the library path?

Comment: I'm sort of 'guessing' here but I assume there are various directories (like those for header files) set in the "path" environment variable. Try using the "Developer Powershell for VS 2019" command (in the VS 2019 folder of the Windows Start Menu) to open your Powershell prompt/window.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871073/adrian-mole) I was able to compile using the "Developer command prompt VS 2019". Having a look at the environment variables, I found a lot of include paths:

```
INCLUDE=
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt
```

Rerunning the compiler with this environment variable solved the problem.

From top to bottom, these paths are for (thanks to [@Chuck Walbourn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780494/chuck-walbourn)):

1. Microsoft ATL (Active Template Library; ActiveX, COM)
2. C++ Standard library
3. C++/CLI (Common Language Infrastructure; .NET Interface, formerly "managed C++")
4. Standard C Library
5. Win32 Desktop development (Windows SDK)
6. Win32 Desktop development (Windows SDK)
7. Windows Runtime API
8. Windows Runtime API (C++/WinRT projections)

Comment: ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include`` is required to get the Standard C++ Library. ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt`` is required for the Unified CRT which is required for the Standard C Library on Windows.

Comment: ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared`` and ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um`` are required for Win32 desktop development for the Windows SDK platform headers. The winrt/cppwinrt directories are for Windows Runtime APIs.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: thanks. I've integrated that into the answer, together with ATL and C++/CLI